# Does .net core handle related look up differently than standard asp.net mvc for child records?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In one of my views I have a series of child tables, where the child table has a related lookup- ie not a grandchild table. The related lookup is a description for a code. In standard asp.net mvc, I can point to that related table and display the description in that child record. In .net core it comes up as blank. If I just display the code in the child records it works.

Am I  missing something?
Code for model, controller and view below:

Traditional asp.net mvc that works:
Model

```
Model

namespace ServeMeHR.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class TeamAssignmentHistory
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AssignedBy { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateAssigned { get; set; }
        public int ServiceRequest { get; set; }
        public int Team { get; set; }

        public virtual ServiceRequest ServiceRequest1 { get; set; }
        public virtual Team Team1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Relevant Controller portion

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        ViewBag.FileUp = db.ApplicConfs.Select(s => s.FileSystemUpload).FirstOrDefault();

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        ServiceRequest serviceRequest = await db.ServiceRequests.FindAsync(id);
        if (serviceRequest == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(serviceRequest);
    }
```

Relevant view portion

```html
<div id="tabs-2">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Assigned BY</th>
                    <th>Date Assigned</th>
                    <th>Team</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.TeamAssignmentHistories)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedBy)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateAssigned)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Team1.TeamDescription)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
```

**For .Net Core** -This doesnt work

Model

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ServeMeHRCore21.Models
{
    public partial class TeamAssignmentHistories
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string AssignedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateAssigned { get; set; }
        public int ServiceRequest { get; set; }
        public int Team { get; set; }

        public ServiceRequests ServiceRequestNavigation { get; set; }
        public Teams TeamNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

relevant controller code

```
Relevant part of controller



// GET: ServiceRequests/Details/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var serviceRequests = await _context.ServiceRequests
            .Include(s => s.MemberNavigation)
            .Include(s => s.PriorityNavigation)
            .Include(s => s.RequestTypeNavigation)
            .Include(s => s.RequestTypeStepNavigation)
            .Include(s => s.StatusNavigation)
            .Include(s => s.TeamNavigation)
            .Include(s => s.FileDetails)
            .Include(s => s.ServiceRequestNotes)
            .Include(s => s.StepHistories)
            .Include(s => s.TeamAssignmentHistories)
            .Include(s => s.IndividualAssignmentHistories)
            .AsNoTracking()
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (serviceRequests == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(serviceRequests);
    }
```

Relevant part of the view

```html
<div id="tabs-2">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Assigned BY</th>
                    <th>Date Assigned</th>
                    <th>Team</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.TeamAssignmentHistories)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssignedBy)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DateAssigned)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TeamNavigation.TeamDescription)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
```

The above view shows blank for the team description. The code for each of these is almost identical...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of EF Core you're running, there's various solutions. In EF 6 (what you're using in ASP.NET MVC), reference/collection properties with a `virtual` keyword participate in lazy-loading. EF dynamically subclasses your entity class, overriding the reference/collection properties (which is why `virtual` is necessary) and adds logic to query the database when the getter is hit. Then, when you access this property in your application, if the relationship is not available, EF transparently queries for it and fills it in, giving the semblance that it's always set and ready to go.

Before EF Core 2.1, lazy-loading was not an option at all. To have these properties have values, you need to either eagerly or explicitly load them:

**Eager loading**

```
var foo = await _context.Foos.Include(x => x.Bar).SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == fooId);
```

**Explicit loading**

```
var foo = await _context.Foos.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == fooId);
await _context.Entry(foo).Reference(x => x.Bar).LoadAsync();
// use `Collection` rather than `Reference` for a collection type
```

EF Core 2.1 now supports lazy-loading, but you still need the `virtual` keyword, which you currently don't have on your entity class reference/collection properties. Also, you need to add in the appropriate services in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
    b => b.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
          .UseSqlServer(myConnectionString));
```

However, I'd advise you to avoid going that route, especially since you don't seem to be aware that any of the stuff I mentioned was actually happening under the hood back in EF 6. It's very easy with lazy-loading to create all sorts of issues like N+1 queries that can cause major problems for you application. It's almost always better to eagerly load any related entities, so you can combine queries. Just because EF Core now supports lazy-loading, doesn't mean you need to use it.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed too ,that I was still using net core 2.0. Will make changes suggested above and retry...

Comment: Changed target to net core 2.1 made the above changes and it worked. thanks for the  understanding on that